# Unable to find module install name / install module in Python

Tags: python, pip

Appologies if this is confusing... I have spent most of today just trying to get the module for "shutil" installed in my instance of Python. I have tried what I thought would be the correct module from pypi.org to no avail. I have upgraded from 3.10 to 3.11 with no change in the message I have received. I am sure the pip install process works as I am able to install other modules fine. Despite my attempts, I continue to receive this message:

```
pip install shutil
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement shutil (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for shutil
```

Yes, I have seen a number of other solutions but so far they do not seem to work for me. Somewhere I even read that it was now an included module. That prompted me to upgrade my Python instance. I have also attempted including --trusted-host in my pip install attempts. Perhaps there is some Python config I missed? The environment paths are updated for the Python 3.11 install.

--corrected typo

Comment: shutil is a builtin module you don't need to install it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

shutil is a built in module, not one you have to install. Simply call

```
import shutil
```

at the top of your python code

Comment: I do have it as an import, should have mentioned that. The editor I am using it appeared to flag it as missing a module, at least how I took its messages. I ran the script from command line with no errors. Good to know it is a built in module... just wish my prior research had turned up more that "I think that might be a built in". :) Didn't help my confidence... ty